# mySQL Syntax Issues

Tags: php, mysql, syntax

I am having issues with SQL.

**This SQL statement:**

> SELECT * from chat WHERE id=16

**Outputs:**

> Array ( [id] => 16 [from] => 5 [to] => 6 [message] => Example Message
>   [time] => 1337674546 )

**The following SQL statement:**

> SELECT * from chat WHERE from=5

**Outputs the error:**

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'from=5' at line 1

As you can see, the second statement should return the same result but it does not.

I am using a new install of XAMPP which includes:
Apache/2.2.21 (Win32) mod_ssl/2.2.21 OpenSSL/1.0.0e PHP/5.3.8 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1
MySQL client version: mysqlnd 5.0.8-dev - 20102224 - $Revision: 310735 $

It seems like I am missing something obvious here, but I can't figure out what is going on.

Comment: `from` is a keyword in mysql language. You might add backquote around this keyword to avoid its interpretation

Comment: (Or, ideally, don't use reserved words :p)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the second query to:

```
SELECT * from chat WHERE `from`=5
```

from is a reserved keyword that you should always avoid using or at least quote to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

`from` is a keyword in MySQL so you need to escape the keyword. Thus, MySQL could treat it as a column name. Use `` to escape the keyword.

You could try this.

```
SELECT * from chat WHERE `from`=5;
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are using the word `from` as a field name, you will need to escape it in back ticks ` as it is a reserved word.

Here is the whole SQL escaped and capitalised:

```
SELECT * FROM `chat` WHERE `from` = 5
```

Comment: Escaping entity names kills portability (though SQL tends to not be portable anyway past a certain point) and offers no advantage other than working around something that shouldn't need to be worked around.  I'm sure a lot of people would disagree with me on this, but I think that reserved names should be avoided, and thus escaping entity names should never be done.  It has no advantage, yet has a minor disadvantage.  (This is with regards to `chat` -- it's of course required for ``from``)

Comment: Yeah, but I'm not here to tell Op to go through his DB/code and change his field names, just to fix his syntax error and explain why. Personally I'd have used something like`from_id` and `to_id` myself.

Comment: Yes, but you encouraged him to escape chat which would imply that escaping is either neutral or has benefits.

Comment: I merely answered the question and explained the reasons behind the problem, it's beyond the scope of SO to preach to users on personal programming practices unless specifically asked is it not?

Comment: Not if it takes one sentence.  And it actually took you more effort to type out the backticks for chat than without.  Though I suppose you could differ with me on whether or not putting back ticks is detrimental in which case I'm just pointlessly harping at you :p.

Comment: `I'm just pointlessly harping at you :p` -
Yeah you pretty much are.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM `chat` WHERE `from`='5'
```

Answer (score 0):

As `form` is the reserved keyword in MY SQL, you will need to use ***backticks*** to escape.

```
 SELECT * FROM chat WHERE `from`=5;
```